# Как сделать кроссплатформенную динамическую библиотеку?

Tags: c++, dll, кросс-компиляция

Мне нужно переместить код с реализациями некоторых функций и методов в отдельный проект, который будет компилировать файл, который будет использоваться приложениями в Windows и Linux. Я так понимаю это dll и so.
У меня есть клиент и сервер. Код, который я хочу компилировать в файл - это ядро проекта, в котором производятся расчёты. Я хочу сделать для клиента возможность работать независимо от сервера, используя этот файл.
Boost активно используется, поэтому, если он поддерживает такую возможность, он бы хорошо подошёл.
Проекты написаны на Qt, но ядро его не использует. Но я бы рассмотрел решения с использованием Qt.

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что у Вас за сервер и клиент, что они должны делать?

Comment: Математические расчёты. Клиент отправляет данные, получает результат. Хочу сделать возможность получать расчёты не только от сервера, но и из файла. Клиент планируется под Windows, сервер под Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Если Qt, то используйте `QPluginLoader`. Пролистайте страницу по [ссылке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) до "The Low-Level API: Extending Qt Applications". Там подробно и с примерами расписано, как создавать собственные плагины.